# How to activate / deactivate floating button with timer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, floating-action-button

I need to show floating button for users and i want them to use it only one time per hour in flutter. So how can i do it? can anyone guide me to add countdown or timer method for floating button?

**This is my floating button code**

```
Widget _floating(BuildContext context,bool isVerified){
    if (isVerified)
    return FloatingActionButton(
      //TODO: customise according to your needs
      onPressed:() async{
      },
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    );
    else
      return Container();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the widget AnimatedPositioned Widget with Timer() to show and hide the button with something like:

import

```dart
import 'dart:async';
```

then in the StatefulWidget:

```dart
// Inside your StatefulWidget
[...]

Timer t;
double position = -300.0; // or any of your value

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  t = Timer(const Duration(hours: 1), () {
    _position = 0;
  }
}

[...]

Widget myAnimatedFloatingActionButton(){
  AnimatedPositioned(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    curve: Curves.ease,
    left: _position,
    child: FloatingActionButton(),
  );
}
[...]
```

And in your onPressed() reset the Timer.
Of course, adapt the _position and Timer initial value to your needs

Comment: Ok i try it bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Set Defaults,

```
  bool _buttonVisibility = false;
  DateTime lastClicked;
```

FAB,

```
  if (lastClicked == null) {
    setState(() => _buttonVisibility = true);
  }
  floatingActionButton: Visibility(
    visible: _buttonVisibility,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          lastClicked = DateTime.now();
          _buttonVisibility = false;
          // change this seconds with `hours:1`
          new Timer(Duration(seconds: 5),
              () => setState(() => _buttonVisibility = true));
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I will try it and tell u soon